# Detect consecutive timestamps with all rows with NaN values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to detect in a dataframe the start and end (`Datetime`) of consecutive sets of rows with all the values being NaN.

What is the best way to store the results in a array of tuples with the start and end of each set of datetimes with NaN values?

For example using the dataframe bellow the tuple should be like this:

```
missing_datetimes = [('2018-10-10 22:00:00', '2018-10-11 00:00:00 '),
('2018-10-11 02:00:00','2018-10-11 02:00:00'), ('2018-10-11 04:00:00', '2018-10-11 04:00:00')
```

Example of dataframe:

```
-------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| geo_id     | Datetime            |  Variable1 |  Variable2 |    
+------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| 1          | 2018-10-10 18:00:00 |     20     |     10     |
| 2          | 2018-10-10 18:00:00 |     22     |     10     |
| 1          | 2018-10-10 19:00:00 |     20     |     nan    |
| 2          | 2018-10-10 19:00:00 |     21     |     nan    |
| 1          | 2018-10-10 20:00:00 |     30     |     nan    |
| 2          | 2018-10-10 20:00:00 |     30     |     nan    |
| 1          | 2018-10-10 21:00:00 |     nan    |     5      |
| 2          | 2018-10-10 21:00:00 |     nan    |     5      |
| 1          | 2018-10-10 22:00:00 |     nan    |     nan    |
| 1          | 2018-10-10 23:00:00 |     nan    |     nan    |
| 1          | 2018-10-11 00:00:00 |     nan    |     nan    |
| 1          | 2018-10-11 01:00:00 |     5      |     2      |
| 1          | 2018-10-11 02:00:00 |     nan    |     nan    |
| 1          | 2018-10-11 03:00:00 |     2      |     1      |
| 1          | 2018-10-11 04:00:00 |     nan    |     nan    |
+------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

Update: **And what if some datetimes are duplicated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to using `groupby` with condition

```
s=df.set_index('Datetime').isnull().all(axis=1)

df.loc[s,'Datetime'].groupby((~s).cumsum()[s]).agg(['first','last']).apply(tuple,1).tolist()
# find the all nan value and if they are consecutive we pull them into one group

Out[89]: 
[('2018-10-1022:00:00', '2018-10-1100:00:00'),
 ('2018-10-1102:00:00', '2018-10-1102:00:00'),
 ('2018-10-1104:00:00', '2018-10-1104:00:00')]
```

Comment: Thank you @Wen it worked!
I simply changed the first line in case of multiple variables.
`s=df.set_index('Datetime').isnull().all(axis=1)`

Comment: Wen, sorry but what happens if the datetimes are duplicated?

Comment: @AndreGarcia what you mean duplicated ?

Comment: I still did not quit get the different , even it is duplicated ,I think we still using groupby and slice to the get tuple

Comment: I updated again! I think is more clear now. 
I have this problem cannot reindex from a duplicate axis